# CSS: How to make a shape that reach the page borders?

Tags: css

I started studying CSS and I'm using an online IDE called `replit` to do some tests.

Today I've tried to create a simple rectangle shape and I realized that it couldn't reach the page borders, so I'm here to ask how to make this rectangle to reach it (https://2.thiagoalonso05.repl.co).

I created an empty `div` and put its class as `greybar`, after that, I went to CSS. Here's my code:

```
body {
    background-color: #181818;
}

.greybar {
    display: block;
    height: 48px;
    background-color: #202020;
}
```

Here's an image showing where I want the grey bar to reach (the red part):

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the default margin and padding.

```css
* {
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

body {
    background-color: #181818;
}

.greybar {
    display: block;
    height: 48px;
    background-color: #202020;
}
```

```html
<div class="greybar"></div>
```